# Eclipse plugin: Place custom icon in Java Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to eclipse but I want to prototype something. The APIs are a bit of a maze. I would like to programmatically place (and then move/remove) an icon on a given line in the editor, preferably in the margins.

Here's an example:

[image: Example location for a custom icon in Java Editor]

Does anyone have an idea, or a good strategy for implementing something that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following extension point [org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_workbench_texteditor_rulerColumns.html)